# differential equation; how to find the general solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how do i get the general solution of $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(10x^2-1)y}{  x(10x^2+7x+1)}$$  please? i have been trying for a while now. I have been doing it as a separable DE and I get $$\frac {dy}y = \frac{(10x^2-1)\, dx}{x(10x^2+7x+1)} $$I can not seem to carry on.

Comment: Use partial fractions.

Comment: Integrate both side, and take exponential both side. The result should be the solution of ODE

Answer (score 2):

you have trouble integrating $$ \frac{10x^2 - 1}{x(10x^2 + 7x + 1)}? $$ this can be broken up what is called the partial fraction decomposition as $$\frac{10x^2 - 1}{x(10x^2 + 7x + 1)} = 
\frac{10x^2 - 1}{x(5x+1)(2x+1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{5x + 1} + \frac C{2x+1} $$

you can find the constants by picking $x$ values carefully. once you know the constants, can you complete it?

---

$\bf{p.s:}$ i get  $A = -1, B = 5, C = 2$  which gives you $$\int \frac{(10x^2 - 1)}{x(10x^2 + 7x + 1)}\, dx =-\ln| x| + \ln|5x+1| + \ln|2x+1| + C$$

Comment: i worked it out to get the integral as -1 ln x + 5 ln 5x+1 + 2 ln 2x+1 + c     is that right?

Comment: @Fara, do you get  $A = -1, B = 5, C = 2$  which gives you $-\ln| x| + \ln|5x+1| + \ln|2x+1| + C$

Comment: yes i do get the same values for A B and C!!! yay..that makes me happy! i think i went wrong with the whole ln thing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(10x^2-1)y}{x(10x^2+7x+1)}
\end{align}
can be seen to be of the form
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = y \left( \frac{2}{2x+1} + \frac{5}{5x+1} - \frac{1}{x} \right)
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{y} = \left(\frac{2}{2x+1} + \frac{5}{5x+1} - \frac{1}{x} \right) dx
\end{align} 
for which
\begin{align}
\ln(y) = \ln(2x+1) + \ln(5x+1) - \ln(x) + \ln(c_{0}) = \ln\left( \frac{c_{0} (2x+1)(5x+1)}{x} \right) 
\end{align}
and the general solution for $y(x)$ becomes
\begin{align}
y(x) = \frac{c_{0} (2x+1)(5x+1)}{x}.
\end{align}

Comment: really??? am i wrong then. because now i have to find c and validities. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about unqiueness and existaeince of a solution.

Part b) of this question is
Using the existence and uniqueness theorem, what is the largest interval on which a unique solution is guaranteed to exist, if
a. y(1/4)= 5? b. y(-1/4)=5
c. y(-3)=5

How do you go about doing that

EDIT
 I figured it out.  you need to keep the denominator factored _ ie x(2x+1)(5x+1).. so x cant be 0 , -1/5 and -1/2

Comment: Please rephrase your answer. (Try using proper grammar and spellings; I don't even know what you're trying to say sir...)

Comment: you get the general solution...then you substitute the x values given and get C.put the value of c in the general solution and get the intervals. but im stuck on how to specify the intervals if x should be greater than 0 and thats all you got!

Comment: But given that the only condition is x =/= 0  wont  all the answers be the same no matter what the intinal condition is

Comment: i really dont know.i suck at it. i just get that for all :(

Comment: so what then is the general solution different? like with the denominator being that?